# How to utilize .java migration format

Tags: flyway

I have added Flyway 5.0.2 dependency to my `build.gradle` and set `baseline-on-migrate: true` to my `application.yml`.

I have the `/resources/db/migration` directory. The baseline entry is created in the flyway_schema_history. I can run migrations in .sql format too. But Flyway does not recognize my migrations in .java files. If I change the .java to .sql and change the content of the file from java to sql then all works fine. In the documentation it doesn't mention any special configuration or anything for the .java format.

How can I get Flyway to recognize my migrations in .java format?

An example java migration I have tried:

```
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.spring.SpringJdbcMigration; 
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class V3__someMigration implements SpringJdbcMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("migration v3");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .java files shouldn't go under resources folder at all. It should go under /src/main/java/db/migration as it is explained in java-based-migrations section of the flyway documentation:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations

Answer (score -1):

Create your java file is created in below package
src/main/resources/db/migration

Unless you changed below environment variable in flyway.properties
FLYWAY_LOCATIONS=db.migration

Comment: can you provide the file name it created in target folder for this java file

Comment: also if you can share the flyway.properties

Comment: there is no flyway.properties but i have baseline-migrate=true or sth like that in application.yml it works if I use .sql file instead. is there a setting I should do to use .java fornat?

Comment: Please share the file name of the java file which does not read. Also the application.yml

Comment: `flyway:
  baseline-on-migrate: true` is in application.yml. `V2__WeightFieldsDoubleToString.sql` is the name of the file. If I make it .java it does not read.

Comment: It says `Schema "xxx" is up to date. No migration necessary.`

Comment: this does not make any sense...you are missing something. Are you building the project? are you sure you are placing the files in correct place? java files goes under src/main/resources/db/migration and sql files goes under /resources/db/migration. After the project build all files should be under db/migration. Flyway checks for .sql and .class files under this. You can check your target folder and see what is happening

Comment: if you are able to find the issue appreciate to give a up vote

Comment: couldn't find the problem. .java and .sql files are all placed at the same location no?

Comment: Please read my earlier comments again. It should not be in the same location. java file location is different and .sql location is different. After project build it will go to the same classpath directory.

Comment: I put both java and sql in `src/main/resources/db/migration`. .sqls work, .javas don't so it's contradicting with what you say. I build from within Intellij. If I make a jar with gradle and then I check the .java files, they are still .java not .class. They're all in `/classes/db/migration` as expected.